# How do I auto normalize in grease pencil weight painting

Tags: weight-painting, grease-pencil

I'm trying to rig a character and I need to know how to auto normalize it while weight painting, does anyone know how I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox is located under the brush settings.

[image: auto normalize button]

Also look at the [manual page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/tool_settings/brush.html):

> **Auto Normalize**
>
> Ensures that all deforming vertex groups add up to one while painting. When this option is turned off, then all weights of a vertex
>   can have any value between 0.0 and 1.0. However, when Vertex Groups
>   are used as Deform Groups for character animation then Blender always
>   interprets the weight values relative to each other. That is, Blender
>   always does a normalization over all deform bones. Hence in practice
>   it is not necessary to maintain a strict normalization and further
>   normalizing weights should not affect animation at all.
>
> This option works most intuitively when used to maintain normalization while painting on top of weights that are already
>   normalized with some other tool.

Comment: Grease pencil uses a different type of thing for weight painting as it's for 2D drawings, but thanks anyways.